# Python Version in the Docker Container Does not change(3.8), irrespective of the version mentioned in the DockerFile (3.7)

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have a `DockerFile` which contains the details about dependencies and libraries which needs to be installed into the docker container. I mention the Python version as `3.7.11` but when I build the container and run it, it always comes up with version `3.8`.

Please find the Dockerfile below:

```
# This Dockerfile is adapted from:
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.2-cudnn7-devel-ubuntu18.04


ENV LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8

## > see this Dockerfile example at https://github.com/TRI-ML/dgp/blob/master/Dockerfile;
ARG python=3.7.11

ENV PYTHON_VERSION=${python}
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list
RUN rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-ml.list
RUN apt-key del 7fa2af80
RUN apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/3bf863cc.pub
RUN apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
```

```
# Using -y is convenient to automatically answer yes to all the questions;
RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --allow-downgrades --allow-change-held-packages --no-install-recommends \
    git \
    build-essential \
    graphviz \
    cmake curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev libjpeg-dev \
    libgl1-mesa-dev \
    libglfw3-dev \
    ninja-build libglib2.0-0 libsm6 libxrender-dev libxext6 libxcb-xinerama0\
    vim tmux \
    python${PYTHON_VERSION} \
    python${PYTHON_VERSION}-dev \
    python${PYTHON_VERSION}-distutils \
    # required by OpenCV3
    libgtk2.0-0 libcanberra-gtk-module \
    python${PYTHON_VERSION}-tk \
    # eth3d dataset etc point cloud evaluation
    libboost-all-dev libeigen3-dev libpcl-dev \
    libsparsehash-dev \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

```
# Set python3.7 as the default python
#RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.7 1
#RUN update-alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python3.7

#RUN rm -f /usr/bin/python
RUN ln -sf /usr/bin/python${PYTHON_VERSION} /usr/bin/python
RUN curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && \
    python get-pip.py && \
    rm get-pip.py


COPY dev_requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN pip install -r /tmp/dev_requirements.txt

# Create a non-root user and switch to it
ARG USER_ID=1000
ARG GROUP_ID=1000

ARG USER_NAME='dummy'
ARG GROUP_NAME='dummy'

##--- Or, change those to first_run.sh
RUN addgroup --gid $GROUP_ID $GROUP_NAME
# Create a user 'appuser' under 'xyzgroup'
RUN useradd -rm -d /home/$USER_NAME --shell /bin/bash  --uid $USER_ID --gid $GROUP_ID -G $GROUP_NAME $USER_NAME

#COPY files/* /tmp/
#RUN /bin/bash /tmp/first_run.sh $USER_ID $USER_NAME $GROUP_ID $GROUP_NAME

EXPOSE 22
USER $USER_NAME:$GROUP_NAME
WORKDIR /home/$USER_NAME


ENV PATH=/home/$USER_NAME/.local/bin:$PATH
ENV PATH=/home/$USER_NAME/bin:$PATH
```

Build Command:

```
PYTHON_VERSION=3.7
DOCKER_TAG="nbansal/nopesac:00"
echo "Will build docker container $DOCKER_TAG ..."

mkdir ./files
/bin/cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ./files/
/bin/cp ./first_run.sh ./files/
/bin/cp ./dev_requirements.txt ./files/

docker build --tag $DOCKER_TAG \
    --force-rm \
    --build-arg USER_ID=$(id -u) \
    --build-arg GROUP_ID=$(id -g) \
    --build-arg USER_NAME=$(id -un) \
    --build-arg GROUP_NAME=$(id -gn) \
    --build-arg python=${PYTHON_VERSION} \
```

Expected to get Python with version 3.7.11 but got one with 3.8 after running the docker.

```
#hostname=$1
echo "Need your input to define `hostname`"
read hostname
#hostname='rtx3090s1'
echo "Got it hostname=$hostname"


DOCKER_IMAGE="nbansal/nopesac:00"

root_dir='/nfs/STG/SemanticDenseMapping/jiachenliu'
u=$(id -un)
g=$(id -gn)
echo $u $g
xhost +local:docker
docker run --gpus all --rm --ipc=host \
    -e HOSTNAME=${hostname} \
    -e ROOT_DIR=${root_dir} \
    -e DISPLAY\
    -u $u:$g \
    -v "/nfs:/nfs/" \
    -v "/nfs/home/$u:/home/$u" \
    -v "/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw" \
    -it $DOCKER_IMAGE /bin/bash
```